# Routes starting by

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have in my website several actions starting by "Filter..." which are used by my forms to update partial views.

I would like to route them easily without having to match each of them. I tried with some regex but didn't get any result.

For example:

```
    data/filterbydate -> should be Controller: Data - Action: filterbydate
    data/filterbyproject -> should be Controller: Data - Action: filterbyproject
    data/filterbyname -> should be Controller: Data - Action: filterbyname
...
```

In fact I wouldn't really need specific routing if I hadn't the following rule at the bottom of my RouteConfig

```
url: "Data/{nodeAlias}"
```

Which forces me to implement a routing for every action in my Data controller.

I have tried things like  `url: "Data/Filter{*type}"` or :

```
 route = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DataWithAlias",
            url: "Data/{nodeAlias}",
            defaults: new { action = "Detail", controller = "Content", nodeAlias = "" },
            constraints: new { nodeAlias = "^(?!filter$).*$"}
        );
```

but with no success...

I am either searching:

- a way of mapping all my filter actions in one route
- Or a way to exclude from url: "Data/{nodeAlias}" anything starting
  with Filter*
- Or a way to avoid routing for these filter actions as
  their URLs are already correctly built to target the correct
  controller/action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what I want using a regex in the constraint:

```
        route = routes.MapRoute(
          name: "DataFilter",
          url: "Data/{action}",
          defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Data"},
          constraints: new {action = "^filter.*|^GetPDF.*" }
      );
        // A route value determines the culture of the current thread
        route.RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();
```